# How to access app group shared container from Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-app-group

I am using window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL in cordova to access file system. However I could not find a way to get the directory path using app group.

In IOS, I can easily use containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier.

Cheers

Comment: Could you post sample code?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question? "could not find a way to get the directory path using app group." - what do u really mean by this?

Comment: I'm not an expert with cordova IOS. But maybe this is something that could help you. https://github.com/protonet/cordova-plugin-nsuserdefaults-for-app-groups

Comment: @Initerworker That example is using NSUserDefaults which I do not think Adrian is looking for.  I believe he is looking for a Cordova solution that utilizes the AppGroup shared folder.  I am also looking to accomplish something similar.

Comment: @Nate23VT Were you able to solve this?

Comment: No, ended up going with a native swift app

Answer (score 0):

To do that one need to write a plugin, that will access shared group directory using

```
-[NSFileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier]
```

as I didn't find an existing cordova plugin that does that.
Writing plugin like that is pretty easy if you're familiar with cordova plugin system.